# Obtener información de SAP para mostrar datos en app web

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmyadmin, codeigniter-3, sap

Muy buenas, necesito saber cómo se obtiene información concreta de **SAP** de igual modo que se hace para obtenerla de una base de datos de Hostinger con MySQL y PhpMyAdmin, que si se invoca la url con Postman te crea un JSON comprobando que los datos son los correctos. Nunca lo he hecho y me gustaría tener orientación sobre el tema de alguien que sí lo haya hecho.

En principio estoy elaborando la web con Codeigniter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yo hice algo similar en PHP.
Lo primero que tienes que hacer es descargar los archivos necesarios para generar la conexión al servidor.

Este es el link para descargar el paquete:
https://github.com/ADOdb/ADOdb

Pones la carpeta ADODB en tu proyecto, después generas la conexión con el siguiente código con una consulta y una tabla para mostrar datos:

```html
<?php
include('adodb/adodb.inc.php');
 $conexion=&ADONewConnection('odbc_mssql');
 $datos="Driver={SQL Server};Server=IP_DEL_SERVIDOR;Database=NOMBRE_BD;";
 $conexion->Connect($datos,'USUARIO_SERVIDOR','CONTRASEÑA');
 if ($conexion) {
 print("Conectado corectamente").'<BR>';

$f1=$_POST['f1'];
 $f2=$_POST['f2'];



$query = &$conexion->Execute("SELECT T0.[FatherNum], SUM(T1.[Debit]-T1.[Credit]) AS ANTERIOR
FROM OACT T0  INNER JOIN JDT1 T1 ON T0.[AcctCode] = T1.[Account] 
WHERE T0.[AcctCode] >= '11000000' AND  T0.[AcctCode] <= '51030005' AND  T1.[RefDate] >='$f1' AND  T1.[RefDate] <='$f2'
GROUP BY T0.[FatherNum]"); 
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Inline form</h2>
  <p>Make the viewport larger than 768px wide to see that all of the form elements are inline, left aligned, and the labels are alongside.</p>
  <form class="form-inline" action="conexion.php" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Fecha inicio:</label>
      <input type="date" class="form-control" name="f1" placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd">Fecha fin:</label>
      <input type="date" class="form-control" name="f2" placeholder="Enter password">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Buscar</button>
  </form>
</div>



<div class="container">
  <h2>Basic Table</h2>
  <p>The .table class adds basic styling (light padding and only horizontal dividers) to a table:</p>            
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Cuenta</th>
            <th>Total</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
    <tbody>
 <?php while (!$query->EOF) { ?>
        <tr>
             <td>
                <a><?php echo $query->fields[0]; ?><br></a>
             </td>
             <td>
                <a><?php echo '$',number_format($query->fields[1], 4, '.', ','); $query->MoveNext();?><br></a>
             </td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
 </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Saludos espero te sirva!!!